# Recursive function landing in an infinite loop. Control will get back to funciton call even after return statement evaluation

Tags: c#

I need to return `UserID` which is in string format when the *linq* query returns a `null` value but control is going back to function call even after the `return` statement executed in `else` part

```
public string GetLastLeafLeft(string Id)
{
    var leftchildId =
        dbcontext
            .NMTrees
            .Where(ll => ll.UserID == Id)
            .Select(tt => tt.LeftChildID)
            .FirstOrDefault();

    if (leftchildId != null)
    {
        return GetLastLeafLeft(leftchildId);
    }
    else
    {
        return leftchildId;
    }
}
```

Comment: Diagnostics question: does a leaf LeftChildID reference back up the chain somewhere? For example, A references B, references A? And do you mean to return `leftchildId` (`null`) or `Id`?

Comment: Also if this is a list of any length you are bound to get a `stackoverflow` exception

Comment: Can you show us the type of `NMTrees` and also some sample data (in C# format)?

Comment: @grant yes i am trying to return ID(which is in string format) which has left child as null value

Comment: /me waits patiently to see if Manjunath will ever provide any clarification to this question which will make the issue reproducible.

Comment: @john yes LeftChildID references back to up the order in tree again. I am trying to return ID

Comment: _"LeftChildID references back to up the order in tree again"_ - you're getting stuck in a loop because your data is cyclic. It's unclear what ID you would be trying to return in this case.

Comment: @ john My point is why the control is going back to function call inside if statement even after executing return statement in else part?

Comment: The debugger isn't always necessarily 100% accurate about where it's debugging. Perhaps you need to clean/rebuild to see where it's really debugging? That hardly seems to be the issue here. You have stated that your data is cyclic (A points to B, B points to C, C points to A, A points to B, and so on), so your code will never terminate, until you get a `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: @john Pardon my data is not cyclic its a tree structure. Data is linear i said controller is pointing to my function call again. Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am giving up on using recursive function, i came up with a solution using while loop

```
 var LLeafParent = GetLastLeafLeft(ParentId);
                while (LLeafParent != null) // To return last node of tree which has null left child
                {
                    var res = GetLastLeafLeft(LLeafParent);
                    if (res == null)
                        break;
                    LLeafParent = res; // returns ID when it has a left node null
                }
```

//Function to return left child

```
public string GetLastLeafLeft(string Id)
    {
        var leftchildId = dbcontext.NMTrees.Where(ll => ll.UserID == Id).Select(tt => tt.LeftChildID).FirstOrDefault();
        return leftchildId;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The last left child is *the node* that does not have a left child, but not *the left child* of node that does not have left child.

```
if (leftchildId != null)
{
    return GetLastLeafLeft(leftchildId);
}
else
{
    return Id; // Node that does not have left child
}
```

Comment: Yes I want to return node that does not have left child. I.e left child is null